# Text shadow in Widget SwiftUI not working

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

I am using this in a widget view and it works fine without the last `.shadow()` line. But adding the shadow won't work. The preview is just erroring out, but giving no particular error.

What am I doing wrong here? The `.shadow()` works fine using it in the `"Hello World"` text of the main app.

```
Text("Some dummy text")
    .foregroundColor(Color("myorange"))
    .font(.subheadline)
    .fontWeight(.medium)
    .lineLimit(2)
    .truncationMode(.tail)
    .shadow(color: .green, radius: 3, x: 1, y: 1)
```

Comment: Works fine in previews in Xcode 12.3 / iOS 14.3. What error are you getting?

Comment: It doesn’t work in a widget extension preview.

Comment: It works for me, so we need more *debugging details* to help you: 1) what exactly is the error? 2) what environment do you use?

Comment: I am using Xcode 12.3 beta. Build settings for iOS Deployment Target 14.3 and choosing the iPhone 12 to compile for. The simple line Text("some dummy text").shadow(color: ... ) works in the ContentView but not in the WidgetExtension View.  The Build compiles successfully yet in the ExtensionView Preview it comes back with a timeout and in the Simulator the widget is blank. (PreviewUpdateTimedOutError: Updating took more than 5 seconds)

Comment: take a look i created a github rep : https://github.com/a3igner/TextShadow

Comment: I'd start by updating Xcode beta to the *stable* version as 12.3 is available for a couple of weeks already.

Comment: Widgets were not introduced 2 weeks ago. Why should it matter. Anyway i updated to Xcode 12.3 and running the same code gives the same behaviour. Have you been able to get it to work? Can you update the TextShadow rep on github with your code? or clone it with yours?

Comment: I checked out your project and previews are working fine. This means the problem is (most likely) not related with code or project but rather with Xcode or system, etc.

Comment: thanks for checking so it must be system related...